# SourceBuffer function fails at appendBuffer and wont append an ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Not sure where I'm going wrong with this line of code:

```
    this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(this.arrayBuffer);

this.arrayBuffer is an ArrayBuffer:

    ArrayBuffer(612916) {}
    [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(612916) [0, 26, 1, 115, -59, -121, 63, -73, 46, -83, 11, -43, 101, -125, …]
    [[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(306458) [6656, -8379, -24669, -31166, 385, -2238, 385, -3518, 1153, -3262, 2177, -32190, 30596, 25189, …]
    [[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(153229) [0, -2068476447, 8403783, 1644265887, -1373601436, 42063785, 47865 -2092334464, …]
    [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(612916) [0, 111 …]
    byteLength: (...)
    __proto__: ArrayBuffer
```

but when javascript gets to line:

```
    this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(this.arrayBuffer);
```

I recieve an error saying:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendBuffer' of undefined

Here is the full line of code

```
    declare var MediaRecorder: any;
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-webrtc',
      templateUrl: './webrtc.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./webrtc.component.scss']
    })
    export class WebrtcComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
      constraints; video; recordedVideo; mediaRecorder; options;
      arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer;
      sourceBuffer: any;
      mediaSource: MediaSource;

      constructor(private signalHub: WebRTCServiceService) {
        this.constraints = { audio: true, video: true };
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.signalHub.getHubStream().subscribe(data => {
        });
        this.signalHub.currentarrBuffer.subscribe(data => {
          this.arrayBuffer = data;
        });
        this.recordedVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('other-video')[0];
      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
      }

      getStream() {
        this.signalHub.getStream();
      }

      startExternalVideo(){
        //this.mediaSource = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
        console.log(this.arrayBuffer);
        this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(this.arrayBuffer);
        console.log(this.arrayBuffer);
        console.log(this.sourceBuffer);
        this.recordedVideo.srcObject = this.sourceBuffer;
        this.recordedVideo.play();
      }
    }
```

Using Angular, using socket.io to get the ArrayBuffer from a node server.

I tried using MediaSource to create a media source first. But, how can I use MediaSource and then add a SourceBuffer if I can't convert the ArrayBuffer to a SourceBuffer in the first place?

EDIT:

Trying with Blob instead of Buffer.

```
this.blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer)] , {'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'});
this.recordedVideo.srcObject = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
```

But I'm getting an error saying:

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided value is not of type 'MediaStream'.

Which a Blob is an acceptable type for MediaStream.

UPDATE:

I previously changed this line of code **this.recordedVideo.srcObject**to **this.recordedVideo.src**. On Chrome I got this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
```

But, on firefox I'm getting this error:

```
Media resource blob:http://localhost:4200/95ebabf2-ed01-45db-b3fc-a91a19c90ee8 could not be decoded. localhost:4200
NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.
Media resource blob:http://localhost:4200/95ebabf2-ed01-45db-b3fc-a91a19c90ee8 could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)
```

Comment: Where are you setting `this.sourceBuffer`? The first error says it is `undefined`.

Comment: Try `this.recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);`

Comment: @jib thanks I did try this earlier. I am then proceeded with a new error:  **:4200/#/intro:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException**

Comment: That means you're failing to catch errors from some asynchronous API. But you're not showing us any code like that, so it's hard to help. Try adding `.catch(e => console.log(e.message))` to the result.

Comment: @jib why do you think that? this.blob was previously an ArrayBuffer returned from my server/api that recorded a previous video.

Comment: @jib the result of what?